# Show that if $P$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix, then rank $PA$ = rank $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $P$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix, then rank $PA$ = rank $A$.

How would I go about this? I don't know if A is invertible or not. in fact, A doesn't have to be a square matrix.

Comment: check if a basis of $\mathrm{span}(A)$ is maped onto somthing that is linearly independent or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether $P$ is invertible or not, one has:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\rk PA\le\rk A$$
since the row-vectors of $PA$ are linear combinations of the rows of $A$.

Similarly, $\rk P^{-1}(PA)\le \rk PA$. However $ P^{-1}(PA)=A$, hence
$$\rk A\le\rk PA\le\rk A,$$
which proves equality.